# NServiceBus Test.Initialize() given key was not present

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nservicebus, nservicebus5

### Update just read the Google group in more detail and apparently it's a app config issue. Will update post after trying.

I was wondering if anyone knows of this issue when attempting to unit test NServiceBus.

Realise I have two initialize methods below but this is to illustrate what I am trying to do.
Stack trace based on request.

> (NServiceBus.LocalAddress) was not present in the dictionary.
> (NServiceBus.LocalAddress) was not present in the dictionary.

Other part of the stack trace I believe is a red herring complaining about InMemoryPersistence. However, there is a Google group talking about this issue too who experienced the same issue which makes me think it's more of an NServiceBus issue rather than a coding mistake.

Google group link https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/particularsoftware/424_6KCv6oI

Should mention seen these posts.

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Testing/issues/20
https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Testing/commit/f761c5391b03b05d967f2e368248c72522051d59

```
public static class CustomInit
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
            //Previous versions of NBUS, specifically 4.6.5
            //MessageConventionExtensions.IsEventTypeAction = MessageConfiguration.ForEvents();
            //MessageConventionExtensions.IsCommandTypeAction = MessageConfiguration.ForCommands();            

            //New 5.2.0 how to setup tests
            Test.Initialize(x => x.AssembliesToScan(GetAssembliesToScan()));

            Test.Initialize(
                x =>
                {
                    x.Conventions().DefiningCommandsAs([my namespace]);
                    x.Conventions().DefiningEventsAs([my namespace]);
                    x.AssembliesToScan(GetAssembliesToScan());
                });
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssembliesToScan()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                AssemblyFromType<ISomeInterface>()
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: So what exception are you getting? is there a stacktrace?

Comment: Updated though there's plenty more mainly complaining about persistent storage but this is the error

Comment: So you are saying upgrading to latest update which includes issue/20 didn't help?

Comment: I have all the latest assemblies, i.e. NServiceBus 5.2.0 and NServiceBus.Testing 5.0.4 and NUnit 2.6.4 which shouldn't matter but added just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After raising the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Testing/issues/20) found that need to include NServiceBus.Testing as part of the assembly scanning. For example:

**Should point out also, for further information I would visit the GitHub link. Further detail about the issue and an explanation can be found there.**

```
    public static void Init()
    {
        Test.Initialize(
            x =>
            {
                x.Conventions().DefiningCommandsAs(x => x.Namespace.Contains("Commands"));
                x.Conventions().DefiningEventsAs(x => x.Namespace.Contains("Events"));
                x.AssembliesToScan(GetAssembliesToScan());
            });
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssembliesToScan()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            AssemblyFromType<ISomeInterface>(),
            Assembly.LoadFrom("NServiceBus.Testing.dll")
        };
    }
```

The key point being this `Assembly.LoadFrom("NServiceBus.Testing.dll")`

Cheers, DS.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the problem was fixed in NServiceBus.Testing 5.0.4

Comment: This might be back in NServiceBus.Testing 5.2.1

Comment: Yeah it's related to a specific version and fixed if you were to use latest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the tests were failing with this error message in NCrunch.

That's probably because NCrunch was running the tests from the following location:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\NCrunch\...
```

The solution was to go to:

```
NCrunch -> Configuration
```

Select the project affected and set the flag 'Copy referenced assemblies to workspace' to **True**.